# cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'const wchar_t *'

Tags: c++

Here I'm assigning Cstring.Format. Is there any way to convert? When I'm using it, I get the following error

```
void Cchart_event_07Dlg::OnMouseDownClientserver1(LPDISPATCH sender, LPDISPATCH args)
{
    /*This Event will display a MessageBox with the series and point information, as well as the XY coordinates.
    This is done when clicking anywhere in the Chart control. */

    Cfx62::_MouseEventArgsXPtr myArgs = (Cfx62::_MouseEventArgsXPtr)args;

    int x = myArgs->X;
    int y = myArgs->Y;
    int pointVal = myArgs->Point + 1;
    int series = myArgs->Series + 1;

    CString strTemp;

    enum Cfx62::HitType _result;
    HRESULT _hr = myArgs->get_HitType(&_result);

    if (_result == Cfx62::HitType_Point)
    {
        strTemp.Format("Series: %d, Point: %d, X: %d, Y: %d", series, pointVal, x, y);
        MessageBox(strTemp, NULL, MB_OK);
    }

    UpdateData(true);
}
```

Comment: The first argument to `CString::Format` is not a `char *`.  Please read the documentation and look at the [examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18he3sk6.aspx)

Comment: "Here I'm assigning Cstring.Format." - no you aren't.

Answer (score 4):

Just add `L` before string constant to mark it as wide string:

```
strTemp.Format(L"Series: %d, Point: %d, X: %d, Y: %d", series, pointVal, x, y);
```